# Python not detecting when a variable is equal to another variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am making a program for my family for keeping ping pong scores. When the score limit is reached, it should end the game and say who won. This works for one player but not the other, and I can't figure out why. When P2's score reaches 11, it says that P2 wins and restarts, but when P1's score reaches 11, it just keeps on going. Please keep in mind that I am new to this. Here is the code:

```
import sys

def defaults():
    global p1sc
    global p2sc
    global p1adv
    global p2adv
    global p1name
    global p2name
    global sclimit
    p1sc = 0
    p2sc = 0
    p1adv = 0
    p2adv = 0
    p1name = "Player 1"
    p2name = "Player 2"
    sclimit = 11

def checkwin():
    global p1sc
    global p2sc
    global p1name
    global p2name
      global sclimit
    if p2sc < sclimit:
        program()
    if p1sc < sclimit:
        program()
    if p2sc <= sclimit:
        print(p2name + " wins!")
         defaults()
        print("New game!")
        program()
     if p1sc <= sclimit:
        print(p1name + " wins!")
        defaults()
        print("New game!")
        program()
    elif p1sc == sclimit - 1 and p2sc == sclimit - 1:
        print("Sudden Death!")
        suddendeath()
    else:
        print("DEBUG: CHECKWIN FAILED")

def displayscore():
    global p1name
    global p2name
    global p1sc
    global p2sc
    print(p1name + ": " + str(p1sc))
    print(p2name + ": " + str(p2sc))

def program():
    global p1sc
    global p2sc
    global p1name
    global p2name
    global sclimit
    cmdinput = str(raw_input("Command: "))
    if cmdinput == "1":
        p1sc = p1sc + 1
        displayscore()
        checkwin()
    elif cmdinput == "2":
        p2sc = p2sc + 1
        displayscore()
        checkwin()
    elif cmdinput == "q":
        p1sc = p1sc - 1
        displayscore()
        checkwin()
    elif cmdinput == "w":
        p2sc = p2sc - 1
        displayscore()
        checkwin()
    elif cmdinput == "name":
        p1name = str(raw_input("Player 1 name: "))
        print("Player 1 name has been set to " + p1name)
        p2name = str(raw_input("Player 2 name: "))
        print("Player 2 name has been set to " + p2name)
        program()
    elif cmdinput == "limit":
        sclimit = raw_input("Score limit: ")
        print("Score limit has been set to " + str(sclimit))
        program()
    elif cmdinput == "exit":
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Command not recognised")
        program()

def suddendeath():
    global p1name
    global p2name
    global p1adv
    global p2adv
    cmdinput = str(raw_input("Command: "))
    if cmdinput == "1":
        if p2adv == 0:
            p1adv = 1
        elif p2adv == 1:
            p2adv = 0
        elif p1adv == 1:
            print(p1name + " wins!")
            defaults()
            print("New game!")
            program()
    elif cmdinput == "2":
        if p1adv == 0:
            p2adv = 1
        elif p1adv == 1:
            p1adv = 0
        elif p2adv == 1:
            print(p2name + " wins!")
            defaults()
            print("New game!")
            program()

defaults()
program()
```

Comment: Off-topic: Don't use so many `globals`, start using Classes. And BTW the `str` call is redundant here: `str(raw_input(...))`.

Comment: Are you sure that code doesn't give you an `IndentationError`?

Comment: Ok, thanks. As I said in the OP, I am very new to this, so any comments like this are greatly appreciated! Also it doesn't give me an indentation error, it's just me awkwardly pasting it into stack overflow

Comment: You could solve this problem, but you're better off refactoring like Ashwini said. If you want to find the problem I suggest you check out the [Python Debugger](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)

Comment: You don't even need to refactor to include classes. I have a 23 line program that keeps track of the score of 2 players, starts a new game when one wins, and enforces the rule that a 2 point lead is nessercary to win.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your progam has some problems with the conditions, this should work now:

```
def checkwin():
    ...
    #call program only if both player's score is less than the limit
    if p2sc < sclimit and p1sc < sclimit:
        program()

    #use if-elif conditions here, and you need `>=` here not `<=`.
    if p2sc >= sclimit:
        print(p2name + " wins!")
        defaults()
        print("New game!")
        program()
    elif p1sc >= sclimit:
        print(p1name + " wins!")
        defaults()
        print("New game!")
        program()
    ...
```

**Demo:**(Changed `sclimit` to 3)

```
$ python so.py
Command: 1
Player 1: 1
Player 2: 0
Command: 1
Player 1: 2
Player 2: 0
Command: 2
Player 1: 2
Player 2: 1
Command: 1
Player 1: 3
Player 2: 1
Player 1 wins!
New game!
Command: 1   
Player 1: 1
Player 2: 0
Command: 2
Player 1: 1
Player 2: 1
Command: 2
Player 1: 1
Player 2: 2
Command: 2
Player 1: 1
Player 2: 3
Player 2 wins!
New game!
Command:
```

Comment: Okay, this works if sclimit is 11, but as soon as I change it by typing "limit" in the command, it doesn't say who wins. Thanks for this though, it really was as obvious as I thought it was.

Comment: @NatZim `raw_input("Score limit: ")` returns string not int. A string is always greater than an int. `'' > 100` --> `True`.